# XPath in Python: getting the html script that contains the extracted value of an Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have two types of xpaths, the first looks like this:

```xpath
//div[@class="location msM10"]//div[@class='categories']
```

and the second looks like this:

```xpath
//a[contains(@class,'job-title')][1]/@title
```

I use `lxml` library to get their values from HTML pages:

```
from lxml import etree
html_text = etree.HTML(HTML_WEB_PAGE)
extracted_value = html_text.xpath(MY_XPATH)
```

My problem is, the first XPath returns a list of `Elements` (in `extracted_value`) and the second returns a list of `str`. So, if I want to get the exact HTML tag where the values were extracted from, I can do that with the first XPath (where I have the list of Elements) by running:

```
element_in_html = etree.tostring(extracted_value[0])
```

but I can't do this with the second type of xpaths. How can I achieve this with the second type of xpaths?

I found a problem-specific solution online where once we have str value, we put it inside another xpath to get Elements, but it didn't generalize well to my project (my XPaths are more varied).

Comment: What kind of HTML fragment would you want to return for an attribute node like `@title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know your XPath selects only attribute nodes you can do e.g.

```
for att in extracted_value:
  parent_element = att.getparent()
  print(etree.tostring(parent_element))
```

to select and print out the serialization of the parent element of each attribute selected.

See https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath-return-values.